# Is it possible to use a partial SRC to find an element/frame?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to switch to a frame that doesn't have an ID and that dynamically changes. I do have the SRC, so I'm trying to navigate to that frame using only part of the SRC since it will change dynamically.

Here is what I've tried:

```py
try:
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@src, 'Text-Within-SRC-I-Want'"))

except:
    print("Couldn't find frame")
```

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@src, 'Text-Within-SRC-I-Want'")))
```

This has not worked so far, and I know it has to be because I'm doing something wrong. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: check you xpath for syntax errors - "//*[contains(@src, 'Text-Within-SRC-I-Want')]"

Comment: switch to frame takes an index, name or ID I think.  You could use "ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt" with a WebDriverWait though... that'll take a locator.

Comment: @pcalkins gave that a try with this code:

```python

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
   element = wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@src, 'Text I want'")))

```

No good

Comment: you don't need the "element = " part.  It'll switch the driver... that's probably not the issue though... post the markup.

Comment: Do you mean the error/exception I get?

Comment: the HTML markup of the page this is running on...

Comment: Wouldn't do any good, this is running on a private server so no one else would even be able to access it.

Comment: Posting the markup would help people to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would find the element using the css selector and search by a partial value of the src like this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[src*="value_within_src"]')

driver.switch_to.frame(element)
```

Of course put more checks in place to make sure you have found the element, waiting properly, etc, but this should do what you're looking for.

Comment: No such luck with this solution either so far, does it have to be what the src starts with? Or can it just be any text that the src contains?

Comment: The *= between src and the value is looking for the value to be contained with the src, so it doesn't have to start with it.  I should change how I word that.  You can find information on how to use different options here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Comment: I did get this to work, my only problem is that it won't move to a new frame with the same src but a different ending. Have posted a new question regarding trying to switch frames in a different thread.